# Filter Count Clause - One to Many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have two table where a versionLog can contain many ProductVersions.

Following Sql Query:

```
SELECT
versionlog.[Name],
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM dbo.ProductVersions productVersion 
    WHERE productVersion.VersionLogId = versionLog.Id  
) AS ProductVersions
FROM dbo.Versionlog versionLog
```

produces a result set similar to

```
Name | ProductVersions
Log1 &nbsp;|&nbsp;12
Log2 &nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;6
Log3 &nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;0
```

etc..

How can I limit the result set to only return Versionlogs with a ProductVersion Count = 0?

According to google I'll need to use the `Having` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `HAVING`:

```
SELECT versionlog.[Name]
FROM dbo.Versionlog versionLog
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductVersions productVersion 
  ON productVersion.VersionLogId = versionLog.Id  
GROUP BY versionlog.[Name]
HAVING COUNT(productVersion.VersionLogId) = 0;
```

---

And without grouping:

```
SELECT versionlog.[Name]
FROM dbo.Versionlog versionLog
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductVersions productVersion 
  ON productVersion.VersionLogId = versionLog.Id  
WHERE productVersion.VersionLogId IS NULL
```

Comment: thx for fast reply. thought id allready tried this.. anyway will accept when poosible. cheers

Comment: Would there be any performance difference or something? or just syntactic differences between the two of them?

Comment: @user3116167 The second one should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

another way subquery

```
select * from 
(
SELECT
versionlog.[Name],
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM dbo.ProductVersions productVersion 
    WHERE productVersion.VersionLogId = versionLog.Id  
) AS ProductVersions
FROM dbo.Versionlog versionLog
) a where a.ProductVersions=0
```